# How to fix this error? make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgstaudioflinger.so] Error 1

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, software-installation, android

I am trying to install this following framework from my Linux Fedora box to Android using there SDK/NDK. But after following all instruction its getting still failed to get build. Any idea how to fix it?

1) Egg

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ git clone git://git.collabora.co.uk/git/user/reynaldo/gstreamer_ndk_bundle
$ cd gstreamer_ndk_bundle
$ git submodule update --init
```

2) Dropped

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7-linux-x86.tar.bz2
$ tar xvfj android-ndk-r7-linux-x86.tar.bz2
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz
$ tar xvfz android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz;
$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7
$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/tmp/android-sdk-linux/tools

#############################
# Try 1: failed 
#############################
$ ./setup.sh
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file ./build.xml
Updated file ./proguard.cfg
android_headers
faad
glib
gnonlin
gst-android
gst-editing-services
gst-openmax
gst-plugins-bad
gst-plugins-base
gst-plugins-good
gst-plugins-ugly
gstreamer
jni
libid3tag
libmad
ogg
res
src
x264
/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/awk: /var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/awk: cannot execute binary file
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !    
/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/build/core/init.mk:258: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
# use this to fix this error
$ mv /var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x69/bin/awk awk_

#############################
# Try 2: failed 
#############################
$ ./setup.sh

> Android.mk
/bin/sh: line 1: androgenizer: command not found
make[1]: *** [Android.mk] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sun/Downloads/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/faad/libfaad'
make: *** [libfaad-configure] Error 2

# use following to fix this above error
$ git clone git://git.collabora.co.uk/git/user/derek/androgenizer.git
$ make
$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/tmp/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/androgenizer

#############################
# Try 3: failed 
#############################
$ ./setup.sh
/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lmedia
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgstaudioflinger.so] Error 1
# How to fix this error?
```

3) Born

```
@TODO
$ ./install_bundle.sh
```

Comment: `sudo find / -name adrogenizer 2> /dev/null`, do you get anything?

Comment: @MaxMackie: No, this is what i am getting: https://gist.github.com/1481194

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, replace with `androgenizer` above. I forgot the `n`.

Comment: @MaxMackie: Please see here the same link and this is showing with your command: `/home/sun/Downloads/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/androgenizer/androgenizer`

Comment: Looks like the setup script is looking in `/var/tmp/gstreamer_ndk_bundle` for the `androgenizer` binary, when it is located in `/home/sun/Downloads/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/androgenizer`. Try doing: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/sun/Downloads/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/androgenizer/androgenizer` then running the script. Do you get the same error?

Comment: @MaxMackie: Yes still same. I even re-installed the android 11 api by applying ./android > GUI. And made sure that i have SDK Api 11, but still failing see here please: https://gist.github.com/1481194

Comment: Try downloading `setup.mk` from [here](https://gitorious.org/mingw-android-ndk/mingw-android-ndk/trees/ad81f2fa93cde51bd3b73a9809bfdd181ee00d04/toolchains/x86-4.4.3) and placing it in `/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/x86-4.4.3`

Comment: @MaxMackie: That error is gone, i got a new one now :P please have a look kindly: https://gist.github.com/1481513

Answer (score 2):

I direct your attention at the *actual* error message in your output:

```
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !    
/var/tmp/android-ndk-r7/build/core/init.mk:258: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Install an up-to-date version of either gawk or nawk via your package manager and try again.

Comment: Is not that error coming from Android-ndk-r7 but not from my Fedora 15? Or i am completely wrong.

Comment: The error is generated by the host you're trying to build this on. That's the host that needs a *proper* version of awk installed in order to build this bit of software.

Comment: my system has already $ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.8

Answer (score 1):

There was a bad version of awk bundled in r7.  Try r7b.